# Is it possible to use all the 16 bits of a float to sample texture in GLSL

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am now trying to sample a texture using floating point vectors but I found that the floating point precision is only 2 ^ -10 bits and the resolution is very limited. So I am wondering whether it is possible for me to use all the 16 bits of a mediump floating variable to sample textures? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You *are* using all 16 bits of a 16-bit floating point number. That's what a [16-bit floating-point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754#Basic_formats) *is*. They have ~11 bits of mantissa and 5 bits of exponent. You cannot *make* a half-precision floating-point value have more than ~11 bits of mantissa.

You could try multiplying the number by 4096 in the vertex shader, but this would only help if the texture coordinate was originally a 32-bit float (before converting it to half-precision).

In short: texture coordinates generally need more precision than this. So you're going to *have* to use a higher-precision floating-point value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, when I am sampling the textures, I found that only 10 bits can be used because the sampler is normalized. I am wondering whether it is possible to use all the 16 bits so that I will be able to achieve higher precision?